# Joining tables on exact string or truncated string

Tags: sql

Okay, so this may be a loaded question.  I want to join two tables on an ID on two conditions:

1. Exact match
2. Characters after first 3 characters match

Also, is there a better way to display tables?

Table 1:

```
Comp ID   Year      
94372     2016      
P1983     2011      
874324    2015      
0342135   2013      
732423    2015
```

Table 2:

```
ID          User        
30094372    TYVSW       
2000342135  PFDBE       
100732423   PLECD       
P1983       ASNWQ
```

Joined Table

```
T1CompID    T1Year  T2ID    T2User          
94372   2016    30094371    TYVSW           
P1983   2011    P1983   ASNWQ           
874324  2015    Null    Null            
0342135 2013    2000342135  PFDBE           
732423  2015    100732423   PLECD
```

Comment: You didn't mention which database server you are using. You can use SUBSTRING or similar function in you JOIN. Or better create one more column (perhaps a computed column) to hold characters are first 3 and use OR in your JOIN.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a `LEFT JOIN` on the condition of the ID from the first table either matches exactly the ID from the second table, or the ID from the first table matches the substring from the fourth character of the second table.

```
SELECT t1."Comp ID" AS T1CompID,
       t1.Year AS T1Year,
       t2.ID AS T2ID,
       t2.User AS T2User  
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1."Comp ID" = t2.ID OR             -- exact match
       t1."Comp ID" = SUBSTRING(t2.ID, 4)  -- match from fourth character of t2.ID
```

For SQL Server you may need to use `[Comp ID]` to escape this column name.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      SELECT * FROM tb1 t1 
      LEFT JOIN tb2 t2 
      ON IF(length(t1.ID) = length(t2.ID),t1.ID = t2.ID,substring(t2.ID,4) = t1.ID);

      +---------+------+------------+-------+
      | ID      | Year | ID         | User  |
      +---------+------+------------+-------+
      | 94372   | 2016 | 30094372   | TYVSW |
      | 0342135 | 2013 | 2000342135 | PFDBE |
      | 732423  | 2015 | 100732423  | PLECD |
      | P1983   | 2011 | P1983      | ASNWQ |
      | 874324  | 2015 | NULL       | NULL  |
      +---------+------+------------+-------+
     5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance, you might want to use two left joins:

```
select t1.compid, t1.year, 
       coalesce(t2e.id, t2p.id) as t2id
       coalesce(t2e.user, t2p.user) as t2.user
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2e
     on t1.compid = t2.compid left join
     table2 t2p
     on t1.compid = substring(t2p.id, 4, 100) and
        t2e.compid is null;
```

The exact expression for getting the value from the 4th character onwards varies a bit from database to database.

One advantage of this approach is that it will only return the full match even if there are two rows that match in the second table.